# Program to calculate NFL quarterback passer rating. Why is it returning 0?

Tags: c++

Hey so the code I made should be working to calculate the passer rating for quarterbacks in the NFL. The program, however, returns a value of 0 for almost anything, unless I put ridiculously large numbers, in which case it gives 100. What's wrong with it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int PassCompletions;
cout << "Enter pass completions" << endl;
cin >> PassCompletions;

int PassAttempts;
cout << "Enter pass attempts" << endl;
cin >> PassAttempts;

int TotalPassY;
cout << "Enter total yards" << endl;
cin >> TotalPassY;

int Touch;
cout << "Enter touchdowns" << endl;
cin >> Touch;

int Int;
cout << "Enter interceptions" << endl;
cin >> Int;

int C = (PassCompletions/PassAttempts-0.30)*5;
int Y = (TotalPassY/PassAttempts-3)*0.25;
int T = (Touch/PassAttempts)*20;
int I = 2.375 - (Int/PassAttempts*25);

if (C<0){
    C=0;
}
if (Y<0){
    Y=0;
}
if (T<0){
    T=0;
}
if (I<0){
    I=0;
}
if (C>2.375){
    C=2.375;
}
if (Y>2.375){
    Y=2.375;
}
if (T>2.375){
    T=2.375;
}
if (I>2.375){
    I=2.375;
}
int PasserRating = (C+Y+T+I)/6*100;

if (PasserRating <= 85){
    cout << "Rating " << PasserRating << ", this is poor" << endl;
}
if (PasserRating > 85 && PasserRating < 90){
    cout << "Rating " << PasserRating << ", this is mediocre" << endl;
}
if (PasserRating > 90 && PasserRating < 95){
    cout << "Rating " << PasserRating << ", this is good" << endl;
}
 if (PasserRating > 95){
    cout << "Rating " << PasserRating << ", this is great" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you've learned from running this in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use data type which is suitable to store fractional value. For this purpose use float instead of int for these statements:

```
float C = (PassCompletions/PassAttempts-0.30)*5;
float Y = (TotalPassY/PassAttempts-3)*0.25;
float T = (Touch/PassAttempts)*20;
float I = 2.375 - (Int/PassAttempts*25);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that but now I'm getting numbers around 55-60 which are still not accurate. Any ideas for why this might be?

Comment: PassCompletions, PassAttempts, TotalPassY, PassAttempts, Touch and PassAttempts should be float as well.

Answer (score 0):

The variable type int is only used to store whole numbers, eg 1,2,3...
Any expression with a decimal will be truncated and rounded down. Since you are doing a lot of calculations with floating point numbers, eg. 2.375, I would suggest you changing your int's to float's